# Checking for an unregistered/missing service

Tags: c#, windows-services, service, servicecontroller

How can I use ServiceController to tell me if a service has been registered or not? In the code fragment below, the check for a null DisplayName results in a System.InvalidOperationException.

Is there a straightforward way of doing this that I'm completely missing?

```
ServiceController sc = new ServiceController("TestService");

if (sc.DisplayName == null)
{
     // unregistered or missing service
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at solution below...    <strike>It doesn't appear that you can...</strike>

From the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.aspx):

> You can use the ServiceController
>   class to connect to and control the
>   behavior of existing services.

Which reads like services must already be registered in order for the ServiceController to work with them.

I guess you could simply catch the exception (indicating the service doesn't exist), but that doesn't seem to be truly exceptional does it?

### Solution:

Use

```
var services = ServiceController.GetServices(machineName)
```

and search the array for your needed services.  If you're just working on your local box you can omit the `machineName` argument.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s21fd6th.aspx